# cannot add reference to .net core Class library asp.net core rc2

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0

I am a newbie in the asp.net net core world and I am struggling to adding a simple ref .
I get an error

Steps

1) Created an "Asp.net Core Web Application(Net Framework)  RC2"

2) Added a Class Library (.Net core) called "ClassLibrary1")

3)Within the web app.Project.json i added a reference to the classlibrary1 like this

"dependencies": {
    "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*", etc...

4) Get error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error

NU1001  The dependency ClassLibrary1 could not be resolved.

I understand why microsoft is doing this as they want to be lean and modular,however 
there should be an option that would add the reference for you like in the classic library.It's a step back in my view.

Is this a bug or its me?

thanks for any reply

Comment: Resharper can be the problem too. You can try disabling it. Tools > Options > Resharper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your project.json in your class library to .netstandard1.4 (or lower).

Your web application is stating .NET Framework 4.6.1, but netstandard 1.5 can only target 4.6.2+ (related to .NET Framework that is).

https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I totally misunderstood the meaning of the -> in the link you shared. I edited your post and added another link which makes things more clear IMHO. But the edit was mostly to be able to remove my downvote, but I still can't... Sorry about that

Comment: @Josh Schultz, I'm having the same problem with the last version of .NET Core. I have changed "netstandard1.6" into "netstandard1.4" but it didn't help. Has the solution changed after they released .NET Core?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. NuGet no longer allows you to get .NetStandard 1.4. It only allows 1.6 through the front end, or "1.5.0-rc2-24027" if you edit it directly in the project.json

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same Problem. I had to manually run "Restore Packages" and the error was gone!