# Asp.net Core project can't reference F# library project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, f#, asp.net-core

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, and I have an Asp.Net Core project targeting the full .Net Framework (4.6.1).  I want to add a reference to an F# library in the same solution, but VS complains that it can't reference projects of that type, (it works fine for C# libraries):

> "The following projects are not supported as references : - Project
>   (project name) type is unsupported by current project and can not be
>   referenced."

I believe the F# 4.1 release is still pre-release, but as I said this is targeting the full framework, it seems like this should work.

Comment: what kind of error do you get exactly?

Comment: "The following projects are not supported as references :
 - Project (project name) type is unsupported by current project and can not be referenced."

Comment: and I guess it's just a usual F# dll (i.e. not created with `dotnet new --lang F#`)? Also  you mention F# 4.1, so I assume your lib is actually F# 4.1? It does seem to be cutting edge, so maybe you want to check in on gitter or slack, someone might have bumped into the same issue.

Comment: It's a standard f# project (.fsproj; not xproj).  It's targeting the F# 4.0 libraries (though, I've tried others).  It's not using F# 4.1 since that's pre-release.

Comment: Did you create a package and reference this via project.json?

Comment: No.  It's not required to reference a c# project.  I'm happy to try that.

Comment: I suppose that's a partially duplicate question. Please check if this question and more specifically, answer, applies to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37452312/717732 It sounds like that's the same problem for me, but, well, please see. **tl;dr:** it'sprobably that new project structure in asp.net core is not based on typical msbuild .csproj/etc scripts and is too dumb to handle 99% of "old types" of projects. _however_ if you build that F# library into a dll, I believe you should be able to reference that dll just fine. Probably even with .pdb debugging info.

Comment: I'm sure you're right about the new project structure being the issue.  I had the same thought.  I can't add the reference from the file.  I get a different error message, ".NET Core projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies in this release.  To reference other assemblies, they need to be included in a NuGet package and reference that package."
I don't think the answer you linked to solves the problem, using the context menu in VS to add the references is what I've been trying.  It just errors.

Comment: Levi, assuming that there are no further "gotchas", the error messages you get and the answer I pointed out, both indicate that it is not possible. There is no solution, it cannot be solved. The answer is "sorry, cannot do it right now" (unless you compile the F# project and reference the dll, or unless you go with the suggestion from error message and wrap the F# project into a nuget - which will probably have a similar final effect).

Comment: To be clear, a direct file reference to dll doesn't work either.  You get the error mentioned above.  Nevertheless, I think you're right.  I assume this will be fixed when the tooling is no longer preview and xproj is removed.